# fix number of model checkpoints to be kept pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

Is there anything similar to max_to_keep in tf.Saver() in pytorch? How can I only save N number of model checkpoints? Is there a built in function in torch for this?

I'm using the function below to save checkpoints.

```
import os
import torch

def save_checkpoint(model, save_path):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(save_path)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(save_path))

    torch.save(model.cpu().state_dict(), save_path)
    model.cuda()
```

Comment: afaik pytorch doesn't have similar utility.

Comment: Please provide some code. How are you saving your models? I usually call `torch.save` inside a loop, you can define some behavior to only save the last N models.